# Cannot get Snowflake Python Connector to work

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use the python connector for snowflake. However, when I use the below python code to verify the connector is working by printing the current version, nothing happens. Every time it just keeps loading and never executes.

```
import snowflake.connector

ctx=snowflake.connector.connect(
    user= 'xxxxx',
    password='xxxxx',
    account='xxxxx',
    region='xxxxx',
    warehouse='LOAD_WH'
    )
    
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one_row = cs.fetchone()
    print(one_row[0])
finally:
    cs.close()
ctx.close()
```

I tried reinstalling pyarrow, snowflake.connector and pandas. I even tried this install to specify the latest version (pip install snowflake-connector-python==2.8.2). I am expecting the output to be the current version (because cs.execute('SELECT current_version()')) but the code just gets stuck and never loads.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run, does it throw any errors or just gets stuck? try to remove the region parameter from the connection, and specify the account as explained here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#using-an-account-name-as-an-identifier

Comment: just gets stuck, no error is thrown. I tried removing the region param and just use the account param and still getting stuck. I tried all 3 types of org and account_name combos and still nothing

Comment: Does your company have a highly locked down network? If so, you may want to follow the instructions for SnowCD (connectivity diagnostics) here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html

Comment: Immediately following the line where you create the ctx, try adding: print(type(ctx)). You should get: <class 'snowflake.connector.connection.SnowflakeConnection'>. If not, you either have errors in the connection parameters or you have a network connectivity issue.